# frm-92095 9n Form builder V10

Tags: forms, oracle

the OS is WIN 7 64 bit

I have problem with running the form. I got the message FRM-92095 Oracle Jinitiator version too low.

I have tried two things but still it is not working:
1- I added this parameter to java :-Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc."

2- In runtime, application server url:
http://:8889/forms/frmservlet?config=jpi

Has anyone has idea about this?

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/craigsoraclestuff/oracle-forms---how-to-s/forms-how-to-configure-forms-builder-to-run-forms-locally  should give you some ideas on variables to look at when changing your frmsweb.cfg file

Answer (score 1):

The solution that works for the following environment:

- Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
- Oracle Forms (32 bit) 10.1.2.0.2
- Opera Browser 12.14 64-bit

Is to:

- Set the Windows 7 system environment variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc."

Also note that for this environment it is not necessary to set a parameter for java.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at http://oracleformsinfo.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/frm-92095-oracle-jinitiator-version-too-low-disable-jre-1-7-auto-update-for-all-e-business-suite-and-oracle-forms-end-users/

It tells you how to install for Windows 7